# Type '()' cannot conform to 'View' while using switch statement

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I have a problem while using a switch statement in a view.
Can you help me ?

Here I want to check the kind of a message for a messaging app. The switch statement could use me to get a specific type for each kind ( for example if it's a photo, it will give a specific type that seems like a photo ) to get the message

But it seems like the switch statement is not conform to a view.

Here's the code :

```
var body: some View {
    
    HStack(alignment:.top,spacing:10){
        if msg.sender.displayName == selfName{
            Spacer(minLength: 25)
            
            switch msg.kind{
            case .text(let message):
                Text(message)
                    .padding(.all)
                    .background(Color.black.opacity(0.06))
                    .cornerRadius(15)
    
            case .photo(let mediaItem):
                Image(uiImage: mediaItem.image!)
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 150, height: 150)
                    .clipShape(Capsule())
            default:
                print("je sais pas")
            }
            
            
            Image(uiImage:profilePic)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                .clipShape(Circle())
        } else {
            
            Image(uiImage:profilePic)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                .clipShape(Circle())
            
            switch msg.kind{
            case .text(let message):
                Text(message)
                    .padding(.all)
                    .background(Color.black.opacity(0.06))
                    .cornerRadius(15)
                
            case .photo(let mediaItem):
                Image(uiImage: mediaItem.image!)
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 150, height: 150)
                    .clipShape(Capsule())
            default:
                print("je sais pas")
            }
            
            Spacer(minLength: 25)
        }
    }.id(msg.sentDate)
        .onAppear(perform: {
            
                
                
            
        })
}
```

Comment: That's because you use `print` in the `default` case instead of creating a view. Try `EmptyView()` if you don't want to show anything.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```
            default:
                print("je sais pas")
```

`print` is a function that returns `()` (also spelled `Void`), and `()` does not conform to `View`.

You can work around it like this:

```
            default:
                let _ = print("je sais pas")
```

This wraps the use of `print` in a `let` statement, and result builders like `ViewBuilder` ignore `let` statements.

Comment: ok thank you very much !!!